# Google Sheets BatchUpdate API changes the Columns Order on insert

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a template spreadsheet with many sheets, each with a header row ready to receive data via batchUpdate.

The data inserts correctly into the right columns. However, the column order is changed to the same order as the items in the value ranges. This breaks formula and makes the sheets messy.

Is there a way to use batchUpdate and the column order is not changed when the data is inserted?

[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWj59.jpg)

[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzT5l.png)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `The data inserts correctly into the right columns. However, the column order is changed to the same order as the items in the value ranges. This breaks formula and makes the sheets messy.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike I have a google sheet template. Let's say it has Sheet1 with 3 columns with headers (Column1, Column2, Column3) and last column with formula to concatenate the values 123. When I use batchUpdate API the data is sorted lets say 2,3,1. Now the my sheet is updated (Column2, Column3, Column1) and concatenated value is 231. This is a simple example. Maybe batchUpdate is not correct and we need to append the data. But with this option I can only do 1 sheet at a time, so it brings another problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your reply and your sample images. Can I ask you about the detail of it?